# What are the guidelines for referring to Java methods?

Tags: java, methods

When I needed to refer to a Java method in a discussion, I used to write it like this:

[`Object.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

However, it's not clear whether:

- The method is static.
- The method has a return type.
- The method has a visibility modifier.
- The method may throw an exception.

So is there a standard for writing Java methods when referring to them?

Comment: Here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: Interesting question. I assume by 'naming' you mean the act of referring to a method in a discussion about the code? In that case, this is more of a 'meta' question than a question about Java itself.

Comment: Your question is misleading. You're not asking what the standard is for writing methods in Java. You're asking how do I call particular methods? You can just look those up.

Comment: By convention method names in Java are "camelCase".  Other than that, name them appropriately to describe what they do.  What does being static or returning a value have to do with anything?

Comment: in general method names in java describe very shortly functionality. ie method with name `getX` should return x, not print "hello world"

Comment: @frant.hartm I often have this problem while explaining my answers on the site, but it can be applied to any context which requires writing (like technical books).

Comment: @David My question is not about [tag:naming-conventions]. I'm asking how methods should be referred in a discussion about code, because my current approach is not clear about some of their components (like the return value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this question is referring to the difficulty of how to *refer* to methods when talking about Java code in a meta context. E.g.

> You should use the [`StringBuilder.append()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.String)) method instead of the `++` operator in this context because...

Now, a method we could talk about can be categorised in the following ways:

- static vs non-static
- has arguments vs has no arguments
- has return value vs has void type
- public vs private vs other access

The above example is enough, in context, to be unambiguous, since there is no great overlap between methods named 'append'. However, if it were lifted into some actual Java code, it could not possibly compile, for several reasons:

- the 'append' method in question requires an argument
- it is a non-static method, and the usage above looks like a static method call.

In addition, because it is written like a static method call, but refers to an instance method call, the reader could be confused.

In a lot of contexts, a solution can often be found which removes all ambiguity by giving an actual code example.

> Try this approach:
>
> `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>   sb.append(textToAppend);`

The problem with this is unnecessary wordiness, and it becomes a little more unwieldy and inconvenient. In addition, it loses the ability to discuss methods in a 'meta' way, and there's no obvious place to put links for reference.

If the class of the method you are referring to is known, one way to remove all ambiguity is to give the full method signature as given in the [Java API Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html), including access modifiers. E.g.

> Try using the [`public StringBuilder append(String str)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.String)) method of an instance of [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). This avoids repeating the process of...

This has the advantage of consistency, and of displaying all of the relevant information, but it does become more effort to type.

If the context means there is no ambiguity, it is reasonable to omit any of the following:

***`public`***`StringBuilder append(String str)`

You can omit `public` if the access modifier is not relevant to the discussion.

`public`***`StringBuilder`***`append(String str)`

You can omit the return type if it is obvious, or unambiguous, or not relevant to the discussion.

`public StringBuilder append(String`***`str`***`)`

You can omit parameter names if they aren't relevant to the discussion (normally the case).

`public StringBuilder append`***`(String str)`***

You can omit parameters altogether if there's no ambiguity in the intention or they aren't relevant.

> Try using the [`append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.String)) method of an instance of [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). This avoids repeating the process of...

This is perhaps the most unambiguous approach while avoiding unnecessary information. That said, the notation in my very first example is very convenient and often will not lead to confusion.

In the end it's down to a matter of taste, but avoiding ambiguity should be the most important consideration, and to that end, adopting an approach relatively in line with the Java API specification itself seems a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The most complete version is writing the whole signature of the method with the modifiers and return types and eventually thrown exceptions as in the standard javadoc:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

Obviously it depends also on the context in which you are using the reference. Try to be as complete as needed and no more.

Answer (score -2):

This is a good guide: [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

A method without a return type will be declared as void, while a method with return type will have the return type as part of the method declaration.

A static method (in a class) can be called from another class without creating an instance of the class.

Comment: The question, I think, refers to the problem of discussing (in a meta context) the names of Java methods, not the issue of naming conventions.